# Custom Query & Rewritten URL Pagination 404

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules

I have a custom search results page that has the url "/mysearch/location/SUBMITTED DATA/" which works perfectly fine.

However I'm now trying to get my pagination working on that page so the URL will look as follows - "/mysearch/location/SUBMITTED DATA/page/2/" but when I visit that URL all I seem to recieve is a "404 page not found".

My current rewrite is performed with the following code:

```
function add_search_store_query_var($vars) {
   $vars[] = 'location';
   return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_search_store_query_var');

function add_search_store_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('mysearch/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$', 'index.php?page_id=200&location=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'add_search_store_rewrite_rule');
```

Here is how my current pagination links are generated:

```
    $total_query    =   "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";
    $total          =   $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
    $items_per_page =   1;
    $page           =   get_query_var( 'paged' ) > 1 ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $offset         =   ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
    $searchResults  =   $wpdb->get_results( $query . " HAVING distance < ".$distance." ORDER BY distance LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );

    $paginationOptions = array(
        'base'          => @add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
        'format'        => '',
        'prev_text'     => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text'     => __('&raquo;'),
        'total'         => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
        'current'       => $page,
    );

     if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ).'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

    if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
        $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
```

If anybody has any suggestions or ideas on how I can solve this then it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Codarz360

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to fix the issue I had.

I added the following into my rewrite_rules function:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^mysearch/location/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?page_id=200&location=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
```

So now my URLs are exactly as I wanted them: `/mysearch/location/SUBMITTED-INFO/page/WHATEVER`